# JavaScript works in JSFiddle but not in html file on a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, onclick

I'm trying hook up a checkbox check event with additional events (such as a dialog display). However, I can't seem to get the click event working when I'm testing my html file in a browser. It does work in JSFiddle, though, which is very strange.

http://jsfiddle.net/rEgAX/1/

My HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" id="myCheckbox" /> Completed </label>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var countChecked = function() {
    if ($("#myCheckbox").is(":checked"))
    {
        alert('checked!');
    }
};

$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
```

The html file that I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // On clicking of the completed checkbox, we want to pop up a dialog for confirmation.
            var checkboxClicked = function() {
                if ($("#myCheckbox").is(":checked")) {
                    alert('checked!');
                        console.log('checked!')
                    }
                };

            $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", checkboxClicked );

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" id="myCheckbox" /> Completed </label>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: More details. What browser? Does the console display an error? We don't magically know this!!

Comment: remove `.ready()` and change `click` with `change`. Checkboxes and radio buttons listen to `change` event. Edit: Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/rEgAX/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must place your code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
});
```

Since your script comes before your checkbox is rendered.

**EDIT**

You might run unto a problem with my first answer. Thanks to Omar's comment and [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events)

It should be this way rather than `.ready()` function:

```
$(document).on('pageinit') { 
    ...
});
```

Comment: Works fine now! Learned something new today. :D Thank you!

Comment: this is totally wrong, I dont know how it got accepted and 3 upvotes. `.ready()` shouldn't be used in jQuery Mobile, why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events

Comment: @Omar I'm sorry about that. I have not tried jQuery Mobile yet. I did not know that they have that difference. Thanks for that anyway, I learned something new today too. LOL

Comment: change your answer to `$(document).on('pageinit', function () {` and add the link i provided as a reference in addition to this http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/ also notify the OP of the changes. thanks and good luck

Answer (score 0):

By default, jsFiddle will wrap your code in an load handler.

Try wrapping your code in:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var countChecked = function() {
    if ($("#myCheckbox").is(":checked"))
    {
        alert('checked!');
    }
};

$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
});
```